# Set the number of reducers to one in MapReduce

Tags: mapreduce

What happens when we set a number of reducers to one ?
Does it write to single file or Does it create a bottleneck (Because by default the number of reducer is one).
Does the number of reducers decided by runtime?

Answer (score 2):

When running the job with 1 reducer, you loose on the parallelism of reducer tasks. The reducer task would receive the output of all the mappers and could be very memory intensive, and would end up writing to a single file.
The number of reducers is one by default but can and should be increased by setting in the job configuration by

```
      jobConf.set("mapred.reduce.tasks", numReducers)
```